# Resizable draggable modal box

Tags: reactjs, typescript, user-interface, react-hooks, modal-dialog

The dimensions of the button in the component Topbar gets affected when I resize a modal component. A video of the problem can be found over here - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BNjJGcyhYzTWXqvx0HJ4at4HSxyQT6cO/view?usp=sharing

The code for them can be found here -

Modal.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Resizable } from 're-resizable';
import '../App.css';

export type ModalProps = {
    isOpen: boolean;
    onClose: () => void;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    getPosition?: (triggerElement: any) => {
        top: any;
        left: any;
        width: any;
        height: any;
    };
    getParentElement?: () => HTMLElement;
};

const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({ isOpen, onClose, children }) => {
    const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
    const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
    const [size, setSize] = useState({ width: 200, height: 100 });
    const [dragStart, setDragStart] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

    const handleMouseDown = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        const titleElement = document.getElementById('modal-title');
        if (event.target === titleElement) {
        setIsDragging(true);
        setDragStart({
            x: event.clientX - position.x,
            y: event.clientY - position.y,
        });
        }
    };

    const handleMouseMove = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        if (isDragging) {
        setPosition({
            x: event.clientX - dragStart.x,
            y: event.clientY - dragStart.y,
        });
        }
    };

    const handleMouseUp = () => {
        setIsDragging(false);
    };

    const handleResizeStop = (event: any, direction: any, ref: any, delta: any) => {
        setSize({
        width: size.width + delta.width,
        height: size.height + delta.height,
        });
    };

    const style = {
        transform: `translate(${position.x}px, ${position.y}px)`,
    };

    return isOpen ? (
    <Resizable
        className="modal"
        style={isDragging ? { ...style, cursor: 'grabbing' } : style}
        size={size}
        onResizeStop={handleResizeStop}
        >
        <div
            className="modal-header"
            id="modal-title"
            onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            onMouseUp={handleMouseUp}
        >
            <button className="close-button" onClick={onClose}>
            X
            </button>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-content">{children}</div>
    </Resizable>
  ) : null;
};

export default Modal;
```

Topbar.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import Modal, { ModalProps } from "./components/Modal";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function Topbar() {
  const [sliderValue, setSliderValue] = React.useState(500);
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpenModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  };

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  };

  const handleSliderChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSliderValue(parseInt(event.target.value));
  };

  //UTC time fetch
  let d = new Date();
  let utc =
    d.getUTCHours().toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    ":" +
    d.getUTCMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    ":" +
    d.getUTCSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0");
  const [currentTime, setTime] = React.useState(utc);

  const updateTime = () => {
    let d = new Date();
    let utc =
      d.getUTCHours().toString().padStart(2, "0") +
      ":" +
      d.getUTCMinutes().toString().padStart(2, "0") +
      ":" +
      d.getUTCSeconds().toString().padStart(2, "0");

    setTime(utc);
  };
  setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return (
    <header className="topbar">
      <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                <button className="active">MSAW</button>
                </th>
                <th>
                <button className="active">STCA</button>
                </th>
                <th>
                <button className="active">APW</button>
                </th>
                <th>
                <button className="active">MTCD</button>
                </th>
                <th style={{ width: "10rem" }}>
                <button onClick={handleOpenModal}>RANGE: {sliderValue} NM</button>
                <Modal
                    isOpen={isModalOpen}
                    onClose={handleCloseModal}
                    getPosition={(triggerElement) => {
                    const rect = triggerElement.getBoundingClientRect();
                    return {
                        top: rect.top + rect.height,
                        left: rect.left,
                        width: rect.width,
                        height: rect.height,
                    };
                    }}
                    getParentElement={() => document.body}
                >
                    <div className="modal-content">
                    <h2>Range Slider</h2>
                    <input
                        type="range"
                        min={0}
                        max={1000}
                        value={sliderValue}
                        step={100}
                        onChange={handleSliderChange}
                    />
                    <p>Value: {sliderValue}</p>
                    </div>
                </Modal>
                </th>
                <th>
                <button className="active">MAIN-INT</button>
                </th>
                <th>
                <button className="active">RAYTHE</button>
                </th>
                <th>
                <button>RAYTHE</button>
                </th>
                <th><button className="active">OP01-126.263</button></th>
                <th><button>Q EST</button></th>
                <th><button className="active2">FPL</button></th>
                <th><button>CONFIG</button></th>
                <th><button className="active2">SYS MSG</button></th>
                <th style={{ width: "10rem" }}><button>{currentTime}</button></th>
                <th><button>MENU</button></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </header>
    )
}
```

How do I stop it from doing this? Is there something that I am doing wrong?